# How to count the number of multiplies in a TensorFlow model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

For many machine learning models it is desirable to compare models that have a similar number of multiplies as to limit the total inference time for the finished product (e.g. when such an algorithm is to be released on a mobile device). Many neural network libraries have functionality that supports easily calculating the total number of multiplies in a model, however I could not a similar feature for TensorFlow.

Hence my question is: how would one go about calculating the total number of multiply operations? Is there possibly a tool that someone has developed for that purpose?